# The sum of of a monotone Lipschitz operator and a Lipschitz operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lipschitz-functions, monotone-functions, monotone-operator-theory

Is there a result which says that the sum of a monotone Lipschitz operator and a Lipschitz operator is a monotone operator?

Answer (score 0):

No, because the statement is false.

As a counterexample, consider the operators
$f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given via
$$
f(x)=x,
g(x)=-2x.
$$